# Is a crash due to Xcode 4.6 build settings?

Tags: xcode, deployment, xcode4

A user has a mini on OS X 10.5.8 and an iMac on 10.6.8. My app crashes immediately on launch with a SIGSEGV error. In trying to find the crash cause, I found one post saying that XCode 4.6 can't compile for those OSs.

What's the oldest OS I can support?

Is there a build setting I can use, or must I try to load an earlier version of Xcode? This is my first Mac app, so I'm struggling still.

[image: My build settings]

Comment: Changing the Deployment Target to '10.4' allowed the program to run, altho not well. On Leopard, it didn't find any COM ports. On Snow Leopard, drop down buttons won't stay long enough to make a selection, and if the window is moved, the controls on it disappear.